# How to enumerate 1-D array in order to plot it? matplotlib histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an array like this: A = [32, 0.34, 10]
I want to display it as a histogram and give the first element value 1 on x-axis, second 2 and third number 3.
Please be careful, I'm not counting how many 32 I have in the array,instead I want every datapoint to be plotted discretely depends on its position in the array(which is unique).

last thing I tried was the following:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2)
counts, bins1 = np.histogram(A)
bins = np.arange(1, 3 1)
axs[1].hist(bins1[:-1], bins, weights=counts)
```

I appreciate every help, since I've been looking the whole day for a solution.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't matter, but in your question you ask for positioning the bars at `1`, `2` and `3`, on the other hand the accepted answer provides a solution where the points/bars are placed at `0`, `1` and `2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to have a plot in which every data point is on its own unique x value. How about a [scatter plot](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html)? You can also display bars instead by using [`plt.bar()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html?highlight=bar#matplotlib.pyplot.bar).

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [1, 5, 0.5, 10, 42, 3]

x = range(len(data)) # [0, 1, 2, ..., n-1]
y = data
plt.scatter(x, y)
```

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

```
plt.bar(*zip(*enumerate(A, 1)))
```

---

*How to enumerate 1-D array in order to plot it?*

Using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), of course…

What you want to do is the equivalent of

```
plt.bar([1,2,3], [32, 0.34, 10])
```

but unfortunately `enumerate` doesn't produce *out-of-the-box* the two sequences we need as arguments to `plt.bar`.

Let's see how we can use `enumerate` to get the two sequences as needed.

First, let's see what `enumerate` does

```
In [20]: A = [32, 0.34, 10]
    ...: print(*enumerate(A))
(0, 32) (1, 0.34) (2, 10)
```

as you can see, we have two problems here, we count from zero and we have 3 2D points instead of 2 lists of 3 elements.

The first issue is easy to fix, it's just an optional argument to be provided

```
In [21]: print(*enumerate(A, 1))
(1, 32) (2, 0.34) (3, 10)
```

the second one is more complex, but is a very common problem (transposition of a sequence of sequences) and the solution is well known, it's a trick involving [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

```
In [22]: print(*zip(*enumerate(A, 1)))
(1, 2, 3) (32, 0.34, 10)
```

Finally, we have our code ready for use

```
In [23]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    ...: plt.bar(*zip(*enumerate(A, 1)), width=0.6)
    ...: plt.show()
```

[image]